# Remove session code from URL to prevent security vulnerability

Tags: keycloak

When authenticating from KeyCloak login page it pass session code as a query param. Are there a way to avoid this and pass session code in different manner (ex: as a header param)

POST https://xxx/auth/realms/xxx/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=xxxxxxxxx&execution=xxxxxx&client_id=xxx&tab_id=xxxx HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to prevent that other than modifying source code. Why do you think it is security vulnerability? Session code is used for CSRF (cross-site request forgery) protection. The actual session identifier is stored in browser cookies.

Comment: Are there any place in KeyCloak documentation that mention this information? In here; is it possible to achieve source code modification via a SPI ?

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on this feature, you can check the logic behind the validation of session code in `org.keycloak.services.resources.SessionCodeChecks`  and other places. To apply modification you have to override `JAX-RS` endpoints in `org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService` since code checks are hardcoded there. Unfortunately, I dont know if it's possible using SPI.